# How to change the URL for an active popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to create a page to display portfolio content. Instead of having each item linking to a separate page I have a popup that overlays above the entire page to display the content.

Is it possible to change the url when a popup is active? I want to be able to link to a specific popup without having to find a specific item on the main page.

Here is the [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/RArnone/m4bLd67c/22/) with my code.

```
  $('#info1').popup({
     color: 'black',
     opacity: 1,
     transition: '0.3s',
     scrolllock: true
  });

  $('#info2').popup({
     color: 'black',
     opacity: 1,
     transition: '0.3s',
     scrolllock: true
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I know code is required. I can't seem to get the external resource working.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my original question.

Comment: I don't understand. How can a user navigate your site if you cover the entire screen? Will you have links within the popup or what? or is that what you're asking? The question is a bit unclear

Comment: I want to know if when you click the "view more" button if the URL can change so a popup can be directly linked to.

Comment: what's wrong with linking to actual pages? and have you considered a show more/show less approach instead?

Comment: Yeah, actual pages is the fall back if this doesn't work.

Comment: i've created an actual html page with your code. I'll play around with it. It can probably be done on button click alright. If i have success later, I'll post it. But about to take a break from the computer for an hour or so! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Take your time

Comment: You should be able to solve it with using hash links. Then you can do your javscript magic with window.location.hash. Google it you should find more stuff about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to make it work, I added these functions

```
$(".info1_open").click(function(){

    var popLink1 = "http://www.rachelgallen.com/popupworks.html";
    window.history.pushState(popLink1, "popLink", "http://www.rachelgallen.com/popup1.html");

});
$(".info1_close").click(function(){

    var popLink1 = "http://www.rachelgallen.com/popup1.html";
    window.history.pushState(popLink1, "popLink", "http://www.rachelgallen.com/popupworks.html");

});

$(".info2_open").click(function(){

    var popLink2 = "http://www.rachelgallen.com/popupworks.html";
    window.history.pushState(popLink2, "popLink", "http://www.rachelgallen.com/popup2.html");

});
$(".info2_close").click(function(){

    var popLink2 = "http://www.rachelgallen.com/popup2.html";
    window.history.pushState(popLink2, "popLink", "http://www.rachelgallen.com/popupworks.html");

});
```

Note that its's important to revert back to the original url on close.

Another thing I noticed is that it didn't work if i tried it from just rachelgallen.com (without the www. before it) so ensure you type in your preferred domain in the link

You can read more about the pushState (which is a new HTML5 thing) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

[working link](http://www.rachelgallen.com/popupworks.html)

Comment: btw, the middle argument is just a title for the page - it can be whatever you want

Comment: Thanks for the help Rachel, I've got it working now.

Comment: hurrah! i knew there must be a way... :)

Comment: @RachelGallen Please be aware that the documentation link will be non-functional in the near future, which is why I made the edit removing the link.